# Does shaking a carbonated soda warm it up?

Tags: pressure, temperature, ideal-gas

I had an odd situation where i left a soda near the fridge exhaust and it developed some ice crystals (i could hear it sloshing). When i took it out i instinctively shook up the closed soda can with the idea that it would heat quicker, and then though "what the hell am i doing".

I think that instinct comes from some half remembered relationship between pressure and temperature. So the question is: does shaking up a closed carbonated soda increase the temperature, and if so to any noticeable degree?

Comment: Check the Joules experiment: http://twt.mpei.ac.ru/TTHB/2/KiSyShe/eng/Chapter2/2-1-Heat-Joule's-experiment-Equivalence-of-heat-and-work.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some of the energy you spend to shake the soda is turned to heat due to mixing and decay of generated turbulence within the can of soda. You can calculate it by knowing the velocity and turbulence scales within the can. @zak kus

Comment: I would say ALL of the energy you spend shaking it. You don't need to know the details of turbulence within the can, as in the Joules experiment @raul mentioned.

Comment: @KeithMcClary, well the Joule's experiment is a controlled experiment which generates only boundary layer/shear stress over rotating disks. In this experiment there is no sloshing mode of flow. The sloshing mode causes the transferring of energy from flow to can body and vice versa.